# Constructing a class in python without directly calling the constructor

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods

In python if we define a class called Start and initialize it with an argument as seen below...

```
class Start:
   def __init__(self, a):
      self.a = a
```

Once defined, and after importing Start into another python file is there any way to make a function or attribute inside the class so I can construct the class directly like this?

```
# Start.make or Start.make()
# Sample usage below
s = Start.make #initializes Start with the argument of 1
```

What I'm trying to do is to have Start.make accomplish the same objective as `Start(1)` so I can potentially create other method of constructing commonly used values without having to manually place the arguments inside the `Start()` constructor. Is this in anyway possible in Python? If not, are there any alternatives solutions I can follow to achieve a similar result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static method, or you can also use a class method:

```
class Start:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @classmethod
    def make(cls):
        return cls(1)
```

To create an instance use the following:

```py
>>> s = Start.make()
>>> s.a
1
```

Comment: This is exactly what class methods are intended for: defining alternate constructors for a class.

Answer (score 1):

With a static method:

```
class Start:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @staticmethod
    def make():
        return Start(1)

s = Start.make()
```

Comment: Are there any caveats to using a static method in python?

Comment: @PensivePastuer `make` will *always* return an instance of `Start`, even if you subclass `Start`. A class method is more flexible; static methods aren't commonly used in Python, as they essentially just wrap a regular function in the namespace of a class.